# I can't install Nvidia GTX Titan into my Ubuntu 16

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have a computer with windows 10 installed and i want to format it and install ubuntu16 but i found some problems doing it. When i tried it, i disable UEFI and secure boot.. It install the drivers ok (it seems) but after i reboot, my computer only display the X log in window and i can't log in.

I tried a lot of things and sometimes i was able to get to a blank desktop (no icons) but where i can't do anything.

I have two monitors and after installing NVIDIA drivers, the main one does not show anything and i can only see my ubuntu in the secondary screen.

Only with noveau drivers (the default installed drivers) i am able to see both screens.

Can anyone help me installing it? Need a step-by-step guide cause i'm a linux noob :)

I have been looking in a lot of websites but none of the solutions works for me :_(

I hope someone could help me 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only Nvidia proprietary drivers **367** and **370** support the **GTX Titan** chipset. Neither are available at the official repositories therefore you should add an additional software source, the semi-official [Graphics Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), in order to get newer versions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Now you should have the required versions available the same way as before, at Additional drivers. It can also be installed in command line. For better results remove all traces of prior installations, before installing new ones, with:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try 367 and 370 but, when i tried to install other times, i found some messages about UEFI and secure boot and adding some commands in the kernel... is that really a need to do? Not sure about UEFI bios configuration and secure boot... Should i leave them off to install drivers?

Comment: Some drivers do not work with secure boot but I think it's mostly WiFi drivers. UEFI is recommended whenever available. The only reason not to use it is in a dual boot scenario where the first OS was installed in Legacy mode. More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI